# How can i use filter from dplyr to filter if the values of a range of columns (eg: columns starts with "w") is less than x or more than y?

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, filtering

I am trying to use filter from dplyr to filter columns starting with w and has values more than 11 and less than 4 ?

```
WBC_abnormal \<-Data %\>% select(starts_with("WBC")) %\>% filter(if_any(everything(), \~ . \< 4 | \>11))
```

error :

> Error: unexpected '>' in "WBC_abnormal<-Data %>%
> select(starts_with("WBC"))%>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~ . < 4|
> >"

Comment: Your code is not readable, please format it with `\`\`\`` . Read the guidelines for more informations.

Comment: Also: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: This said you could try with `~ . < 4 | . > 11`

Comment: Or use `between(., 4, 11)` to replace your `. < 4 | >11`